# Change Font of Text Area as Per DropdownList Selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdownlist and a text area in my html file and code is as below

```
<select id='ddlViewBy' name='ddlViewBy' onchange='applyfonttotextarea()'>
<option value = '1'>Arial</option>
<option value = '2' selected = 'selected'>Comic Sans</option>
<option value ='3'>Courier New</option>
</select>"
```

Now in the above code I have added an onchange method in the dropdownlist as applyfonttotextarea()
In this method, I need to write a logic in javascript to apply the selected font style in the text area.
How to write that function.

For ex. In the textarea I have entered " Hello Friends. How are You? "and I have selected the "Hello" word in it and select the Courier New option from the dropdown, the textarea's "Hello" should be in Courier New font.Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to implement a `change` event handler to your `<select>` element where:

1. Identify the newly selected option of that `<select>`
2. Read the text of that selected option
3. Apply that text as the active font family to the `<textarea>` you want to update

In code this can be achieved as:

```js
document.getElementById('ddlViewBy').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  
  /* Get select element of change event */
  const selectElement = event.currentTarget;
  
  /* Get selected option (step 1) */
  const selectedOption = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex];
  
  /* Get font family name from selected option's text (step 2) */
  const fontFamily = selectedOption.text;
  
  /* Get text area, and update it's fontFamily style (step 3) */
  document.getElementById('myTextarea').style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
  
});
```

```html
<select id='ddlViewBy' name='ddlViewBy'>
  <option value='1'>Arial</option>
  <option value='2' selected='selected'>Comic Sans</option>
  <option value='3'>Courier New</option>
</select>
<br/>
<textarea id="myTextarea">some text</textarea>
```

Note also that this aproach means that the inline binding of `onchange='applyfonttotextarea()'` is no longer required.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Dacre. This helps. But as I mentioned only selected text should get changed when we are changing the dropdown.Here it is changing the whole text.Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry about that, missed that detail (was reading selection as the selected option but didnt notice the mention of per-word selection). Unfortunatly that's not possible however it would be doable with content editable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content